# Oracle Cloud REST API Endpoints for financial table extraction

Tags: rest, extract, endpoint, oracle-fusion-middleware

We're trying to connect to an Oracle database using REST APIs to extract data from certain GL Tables.

Apologies as i'm quite unfamiliar with Oracle but we're looking at Oracle Fusion Cloud Financials APIs here - https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/financials/23c/farfa/api-journal-batches-descriptive-flexfields.html

Is it possible to find data from specific financial GL Tables (e.g. FND_ID_FLEX_SEGMENTs, FND_FLEX_VALUES_VL, GL_PERIODS) and extract the data within by connecting to an endpoint? The Flex tables in particular seem difficult to narrow down which ones we would need.

We've found Endpoints such as /fscmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/journalBatches which seem to line up with the GL_JE_BATCHES table. Other JE Tables seem to follow a similar naming convention and make it easier.